# Meaning of up to, in advance, more than, and within on this sentence

Tags: meaning

If I have following statement:

> Allow to purchase up to 100 days in advance, when user selects more
>   than 100 days, the prompt message will be “Please buy within 100
>   days”.

Can user buy or not buy in 100th days?

Comment: The user cannot buy more that 100 days in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **up to**: indicating a maximum amount

Example: ‘the process is expected to take up to two years’

(#2 in http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/up-to)

> **in advance**: ahead in time

Example: ‘you need to book weeks in advance’

(http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in-advance?q=in+advance)

> **more than**: (comparative of `much' used with mass nouns) a quantifier
>   meaning greater in size or amount or extent or degree

Example: more than a gallon (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/more+than)

> **within**: not exceeding the limits or extent of in distance or time

Example: got within ten miles of home; stayed within earshot; arrived within two days (prep. #2(a) in http://www.thefreedictionary.com/within)

What your example means is: *A user can start buying the item from 100 days before an actual date of what the item is for (e.g., concert, movie...), and if the user tries to buy the item on a day that is more than 100 days (101 days or more) before the day of the concert, movie, or whatever the item is for, the user will receive a message which says "Please start buying the item from a day that is 100 days or less until the concert, movie, etc..."*

So, NO, the user can't buy the item more than 100 days in advance.